# How to set up a top level element to show the download progress?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to send multiple get requests and let a tkinter label to show the progress, but I noticed the toplevel only shows up after all the requests have been done.

How can I fix this?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import requests

window = tk.Tk()

def download():
    global window
    top = tk.Toplevel(window)
    progress_text = tk.StringVar()

    tk.Label(top, textvariable=progress_text, font=('Arial', 12))


    url_list = [' http://www.yahoo.com', ' http://www.google.com', ' http://www.amazon.com']
    [requests.get(c) for c in url_list]

    for i in range(len(url_list)):
        progress_text.set('Done: {}'.format(i/len(url_list)))
        requests.get(url_list[i])
        print('done')




tk.Button(window, text='download', command=download).pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: To do this properly you need to put the download portion of your code in a separate thread. For a hacky fix add `top.update()` inside the for loop.

Comment: @Novel Hi, so I do need to start a new thread? I thought when I started the new toplevel widget, it triggered a new thread.

Comment: The documentation for `concurrent.futures` has [an example very similar to your code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example). All that's left is you need to add an event generation in download function and use it in tkinter to update your progressbar.

Comment: No, Toplevel does not start a new thread. In fact tkinter is very resistant to being run from more than one thread.